# Beamer file not being compiled when in a folder on macair (MACOS BIG SUR 11.6.4

Tags: beamer, pdftex, compilation-error

My beamer file gets compiled if I have it on my desktop.
But if I place it in a folder on my desktop I get the the following error when I use TexShop:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./enumvaragrp.tex/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: getcwd: Operation not permitted
```

How do I set this right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you able to compile a simple test document -- e.g., `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Hello World \end{document}` -- successfully on the Mac? A separate thought: Have you tried updating your [MacTeX distribution](https://tug.org/mactex/)? Incidentally, which TeX distribution do you employ on your desktop machine, and when did you last update it?

Comment: The simple test document also did not compile when it was placed inside a folder. It compiled properly when I moved it to the desktop. I use TexShop and I updated it just now and tried compiling the file when it was in the folder but once again it's not working. I am wondering if it's some kind of permission issue for the folder but have no idea on how to put it right.

Comment: Please provide more usable information. A claim such as "again it's not working" isn't helpful. What exactly does "it's not working" entail? E.g. are you getting error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say? You mention that while the test document I suggested compiles on the desktop (so, "it must be working" at least in some cases...) but not when "placed inside a folder." *Which folder*? What are the read and write permissions on this folder? You say you updated TeXshop, but you apparently didn't update the TeX distribution -- MacTeX -- itself. Why not?

Comment: I have updated MacTex as well now. When I compile a simple TeX file which is inside a folder on my desktop, the error message I get is:                                 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

Comment: The log file has: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.3.25)  25 MAR 2022 18:06 entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled. file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled. **Test.tex (./Test.tex
entering extended mode (./Test.tex/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: getcwd: Operation not permitted

Comment: If I remove the file from the folder on the desktop and then compile, then there is no problem. Likewise if the file is my dropbox folder which is on my harddisk there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks for these responses. It would appear that there's a problem with read-write permissions on the `Desktop` folder and/or some of its subfolders. That's not really a TeX probleml. I can only suggest that you ask new questions on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.